# How to search for pattern containing brackets and other special characters in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I am trying to do the below pattern search in the "output2" file but it does not give the desired output even though the status of the grep command shows success.

```
➜  automate git:(master) ✗ grep -F "@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")" output2
➜  automate git:(master) ✗ grep -nF "@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")" output2
➜  automate git:(master) ✗ echo $?
0
➜  automate git:(master) ✗
```

Contents of the output2 file below:

```
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:1549:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:3254:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:4558:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:5438:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:5744:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:6986:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:7344:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus,
```

Comment: Tried single quotes to quote the string instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced " with \" and it solved the problem .

```
grep -F "@PreAuthorize(\"isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')\")" output2
```

Answer (score 4):

The string needs to be properly quoted:

```
$ grep -F '@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, '\''MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE'\'')")' output2
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:1549:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:3254:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:4558:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:5438:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:5744:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
/home/workspace/OutputWithMessages.txt:6986:+ @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#updateStatus, 'MAX_LOAN_AMOUNT_FOR_APPROVE')")
```

The shell treats all characters inside of a single quoted string as literal characters *except* for a single quote.  To enter a single quote as part of the string, use `'\''`.

`'\''` works in three steps: first it terminates the single quoted string with `'`, then it adds an escaped single-quote with `\'`, and lastly it starts a new single-quoted string with `'`.

Comment: No using back slash for single quote is not required for grep

Comment: @Zack You are right that grep doesn't need it but that is _not_ why it is there: the backslash is needed so that the shell treats the single-quote as a literal character and therefore passes it on to grep.

Comment: yes. You are right in correctly using backslash. But for my problem it is not required. :) Without using backslash with double quotes, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Zack Your solution does work in this case but it does require care: the shell will do variable, command, and arithmetic expansions on double-quoted strings.  It you want to be sure that you string is taken literally, single-quotes are safer.